# Find the Path between two nodes in JavaScript on custom data structure

Tags: javascript, graph, underscore.js, lodash

Hi I have a connections array as below:

```
var connections =[

    {
      "source": "l1",
      "target": "l2"
    },
    {
      "source": "l2",
      "target": "l4"
    },
    {
      "source": "l2",
      "target": "l3"
    },
    {
      "source": "l4",
      "target": "l5"
    },   

]
```

It goes on with source and target. Now want to find the path between two nodes using some function. let's say function `findConnections("l2", "l5")` will return the array like below

```
var answer =[

        {
          "source": "l2",
          "target": "l4"
        },
        {
          "source": "l4",
          "target": "l5"
        }, 
]
```

I have no idea how can I achieve this? I tried simple JavaScript but failed. I think using *underscore.js* or *lodash.js* we can achieve this? It will be really helpful if anyone provide solution or give hints?

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's a simple solution:

1. build a graph from the given edges:

   [image: graph]
2. use simple [breadth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find a path

```js
const addNode = (graph, node) => {
  graph.set(node, {in: new Set(), out: new Set()});
};

const connectNodes = (graph, source, target) => {
  graph.get(source).out.add(target);
  graph.get(target).in.add(source);
};

const buildGraphFromEdges = (edges) => edges.reduce(
  (graph, {source, target}) => {
    if (!graph.has(source)) {
      addNode(graph, source);
    }

    if (!graph.has(target)) {
      addNode(graph, target);
    }

    connectNodes(graph, source, target);

    return graph;
  },
  new Map()
);

const buildPath = (target, path) => {
  const result = [];

  while (path.has(target)) {
    const source = path.get(target);
    result.push({source, target});
    target = source;
  }

  return result.reverse();
};

const findPath = (source, target, graph) => {
  if (!graph.has(source)) {
    throw new Error('Unknown source.');
  }

  if (!graph.has(target)) {
    throw new Error('Unknown target.');
  }

  const queue = [source];
  const visited = new Set();
  const path = new Map();

  while (queue.length > 0) {
    const start = queue.shift();

    if (start === target) {
      return buildPath(start, path);
    }

    for (const next of graph.get(start).out) {
      if (visited.has(next)) {
        continue;
      }

      if (!queue.includes(next)) {
        path.set(next, start);
        queue.push(next);
      }
    }

    visited.add(start);
  }

  return null;
};

//  A --* B
//      / | \
//     *  |  *
//    C   |   D --* E
//     \  |  /     *
//      * * *     /
//        F------/

const graph = buildGraphFromEdges([
  { source: 'A', target: 'B' },
  { source: 'B', target: 'C' },
  { source: 'B', target: 'D' },
  { source: 'B', target: 'F' },
  { source: 'C', target: 'F' },
  { source: 'D', target: 'E' },
  { source: 'D', target: 'F' },
  { source: 'F', target: 'E' },
]);

console.log('A -> A', findPath('A', 'A', graph)); // []
console.log('A -> F', findPath('A', 'F', graph)); // [{source: 'A', target: 'B'}, {source: 'B', target: 'F'}]
console.log('A -> E', findPath('A', 'E', graph)); // [{source: 'A', target: 'B'}, {source: 'B', target: 'D'}, {source: 'D', target: 'E'}]
console.log('E -> A', findPath('E', 'A', graph)); // null
```

**Note** that I understood your input to form a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). If instead it's meant to be a undirected graph the solution could be simplified a bit.

Comment: @NikitaMarinosyan Yes it should work (because of BFS). My comment in the answer was with regards to how the graph is constructed (in/out sets) which could be simplified to a simple `edges` (or similar).

Comment: @Yoshi what if I want to add weight to each path and then find the cheapest path

Comment: @Yoshi, to make this undirected what simplification could be made? I added `connectNodes(graph, target, source);` below `connectNodes(graph, source, target);` to achieve it...

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion and walk the "list"

```
function find(list, from, to) {
    // find the current "source" 
    let current = list.find(v => v.source === from);

    if (!current) // no current? u got problems
        throw new Error("No from in list");

    // are we there yet?
    if (current.target === to)
        return current;

    // no we're not ... so keep searching with new "source"
    return [current].concat(find(list, current.target, to));
}
```

Comment: its not working for below connection objects: 

var connections=[
{source:"l1", target:"l2"},
{source:"l2", target:"l3"},
{source:"l2", target:"l4"},
{source:"l2", target:"l5"},
{source:"l3", target:"l6"},
{source:"l4", target:"l6"},
]

find(connections, "l1", "l5");
gives error

Comment: @realcodes Really? There's no ```source: "l6"``` in your list. What's the code supposed to do?

Comment: Hi, This was just the example of connections. there are many connections like that. So It's  like graph and edges problem and we need to find a path between them. Check my question I said this connections will go on with source and target. I need some generic solution

Comment: @realcodes I know what a graph is, hence the recursion. Your data does not have an object where ```source = "l6"``` but it has a ```target = "l6"``` on the 5th object in the array. Where is the code supposed to go? Your data is implying an edge to nowhere! Hence the error that i **specifically** raise. You really can't get more generic than this.

Comment: node "l6" is the last node in the graph so there is no source specified. Just draw the graph using edges in the array and you can see the whole graph. now if I wan to find the path between l1 to l5. I cannot get the answer using your solution. the solution failed when there is more than one edge from same nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I spent waaaaay too much time on this and I'm pretty certain there's a more elegant solution, but I'll see if I can add comments and explain myself.

```js
// Add some more connections. Make some of them out
// of order just for fun
let connections = [{
    source: 'l1',
    target: 'l2'
  },
  {
    source: 'l1',
    target: 'l3'
  },
  {
    source: 'l2',
    target: 'l4'
  },
  {
    source: 'l2',
    target: 'l3'
  },
  {
    source: 'l4',
    target: 'l5'
  },
  {
    source: 'l3',
    target: 'l6'
  },
  {
    source: 'l3',
    target: 'l5'
  },
  {
    source: 'l4',
    target: 'l6'
  }
];

// I just realized that I didn't call this
// function what you wanted it called but
// it should be fine

let answers = findPaths(connections, 'l1', 'l5');
console.log(JSON.stringify(answers, null, 2));

function findPaths(connections, start, end) {
  // first, build a tree, for loads of connections,
  // this is probably slow as hell
  let tree = buildTree(
    connections,
    findConnection(connections, start),
    null
  );
  
  // make the tree into all the different paths
  // also probably slow as hell. Could prune the
  // tree if I could figure out how to implement
  // a backtracking algoritm in javascript but 
  // I couldn't figure it out from the wikipedia
  // article so I skipped it
  let allPaths = buildPaths(tree, []);
  
  // pare down the paths to ones that fit the start
  // and end points
  let goodPaths = verifyPaths(allPaths, start, end);
  
  // reformat that thing to match what you wanted
  return format(goodPaths);
}

// so this thing just runs through the connections
// array and returns an array of elements where the
// source property matches the source argument
function findConnection(connections, source) {
  return connections.filter(conn => conn.source === source);
}

// So this returns an array that contains a tree
// Probably a better way to do this, but...
function buildTree(connections, nodes, parent) {
  // for each node...
  return nodes.map(node => {
    // had to cheat here, just add the node's parent
    // to the node. That way, we don't have to think
    // about it later
    node.parent = parent;
    
    // find any other connections whose source property
    // matches our target property.
    node.path = findConnection(connections, node.target);
    
    // if some were found, then...
    if (node.path && node.path.length > 0) {
      // build that sub-tree. Here, I cheated big-time
      // and made the third param (parent) an object
      // that had the properties I wanted later.
      // It's just easier.
      buildTree(connections, node.path, {
        source: node.source,
        target: node.target,
        parent: node.parent
      });
    }
    // done slapping this around, return it
    return node;
  });
}

// so this is a part could be better. Probably could be
// replaced by Array.reduce, but I'm too lazy. This
// turns the "tree" into an array of all of the paths
// from beginning to end. Many of the paths will be 
// filtered out later so it could be made more efficient
function buildPaths(tree, prev) {
  tree.forEach(step => {
    if (step.path.length > 0) {
      buildPaths(step.path, prev);
    } else {
      prev.push(step);
    }
  });
  return prev;
}

// filter out the paths that don't match the specified
// start and end. We should have good paths now...in
// the wrong format, but we'll fix that up later...
function verifyPaths(paths, start, end) {
  return paths.filter(path => path.target === end).filter(path => {
    while (path.parent) {
      path = path.parent;
    }
    return path.source == start;
  });
}

// alright, go ahead and flatten out the good paths
// into the requested format
function format(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    let temp = [];
    temp.unshift({
      source: el.source,
      target: el.target
    });
    while (el.parent) {
      el = el.parent;
      temp.unshift({
        source: el.source,
        target: el.target
      });
    }
    return temp;
  });
}
```

Comment: Looks like I have  a bug somewhere that repeats a path. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return a JSON object, as was specified in the question. It will also check if both arguments, as well as the connection between them is present in the JSON. I will leave it to the author to test for other edge cases.

```js
var findConnections = function(json,from,to) {

  // JSON is an unordered structure, so let's compile two arrays for ease of searching
  var sources = [], targets = [];
  for ( node of json ) {
    sources.push(node.source);
    targets.push(node.target);
  }

  // Select each 'from' element from the 'sources' array, get its target...
  for(var i=0;i<sources.length;i++) {
    if( (fromIndex = sources.indexOf(from,i)) < 0 ) { throw new Error('Connection could not be established.'); }
    var fromTarget = targets[fromIndex];

    // ...then look for the connected 'to' in the 'targets' array
    for(var j=0;j<sources.length;j++) {
      if( (toIndex = sources.indexOf(fromTarget,j)) < 0 ) { continue; }

      // If we have a match, compile and return a JSON object. If not, we'll keep looping and if we loop out, an error will be thrown below
      if( targets[toIndex] == to ) {
        return [
                {
                  'source':sources[fromIndex],
                  'target':targets[fromIndex]
                },
                {
                  'source':sources[toIndex],
                  'target':targets[toIndex]                
                }
                ];
      }          
    }
  }

  throw new Error('Connection could not be established.');
}
```

Test it as following:

`var answer = findConnections(connections,'l2','l5');
console.log(answer);`

Comment: I am finding some generic solution that work on all cases. Think this problem like edges and you need to find the path. The example that I gave on question is just small part of connections. It have more edges and some are parallel.

Comment: As the JSON objects are not ordered, it is hard to search and reference the individual object nodes. Your best bet is either to change the structure of how you store/retrieve data, or if this is not possible, to walk the JSON object and create an array/hash table/... first and then run your queries.